# Trying to make a random number guesser on javascript and its showing a syntax error. Anyone know a fix?

Tags: javascript

Heres my code:

```
function TheNumber(){
  let Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
  DaGuess()
}

function DaGuess(){
  let Guess = prompt('Pick your number between 1 - 100')
  if (Guess > Number){
    alert('Try picking a number lower than ' + this.Guess)
    DaGuess()
  }
  if (Guess < Number){
    alert('Try picking a number higher than ' + this.Guess)
    DaGuess()    
  }
  if (Guess == Number){
    let playagain = prompt('Well done! Wanna play again? Y/N')
    if (playagain == 'Y' or playagain == 'y'){
      TheNumber()
    }
  }
  else{
    alert('Thanks for playing!')
  }
}

TheNumber()
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at /script.js:19:26

Im completely new to javascript so if the code is awful i am sorry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your syntax error is: or should be ||

Comment: On line 19, replace `or` with `||` and remove `{`

Answer (score 1):

The`or` keyword doesn't exist in JS, you must use `||`.

```js
if (playagain === 'Y' || playagain === 'y'){
    TheNumber()
}
```

Comment: oh my god i cannot believe i forgot that. i had just converted from python to javascript so its a little different. Thanks.

Comment: @Rocky By the way, instead of using `==` you should use `===` in JS, it's not really a syntax error but the `===` is more reliable, it's a strict equality comparison. For ex `2=="2"` returns true in JS, which is not so great...